# Google Sheets: ArrayFormula w/ Multiple Conditions

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, counting, countif

Google Sheet: using the formula below, I need it to return the # of records in F2:F214 with values of "11" or "22" or "33" that only have a value of "Y" or a "P" in H2:H214. `H2:H214,{"Y"}` but if I try `H2:H214,{"Y","P"}` I get a #VALUE! error?

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(COUNTIFS(F2:F214,{"11","22","33"},H2:H214,{"Y","P"})))
```

It's close, but I don't understand why adding the 2nd variable in the 2nd range throws it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(REGEXMATCH(F2:F214&""; "11|22|33")*REGEXMATCH(H2:H214; "Y|P")))
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you! Can I ask though, why? Was there a syntax error in my formula, or does Google not like a 2nd set of variables, or too many variables for countifs, ??

Comment: @chevy454 not rly syntax error but improper usage of arrays `{}` in conjunction with countifs which is one dimensional. OR in countifs would look like: `=COUNTIF(A:A, 11)+COUNTIF(A:A, 22)+COUNTIF(A:A, 33)`